# How do match strings inside SQL injections in Stata?

Tags: sql, stata, sql-injection

I am trying to inject SQL statements inside Stata in the following way:

```
obdc load, exec('"select * from table_name as u, l2010 as lv where u.IntUft='I'"') dsn("some_db") clear
```

But this gives me a `r(198)` error saying `table() or exec() is required`.

When i tried the same code with an integer, it did work. That means,

```
obdc load, exec('"select * from table_name as u, l2010 as lv where u.Ar=2000"') dsn("some_db") clear
```

works.

Any idea on how to compare Strings inside SQL statements like that in Stata?

Comment: isn't it enoght to have only double quotes `obdc load, exec("select * from table_name as u, l2010 as lv where u.IntUft='I'") dsn("some_db") clear`

Comment: Please respond to helpful answer from @TheIceBear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used `obdc` myself, so I am not sure it is the full solution, but I spot two Stata syntax bugs.

In Stata, the leading single quote in a compounded string must be a back quote `` ` ``. So you need `` exec(`"select ``.

Similarly, when referencing a local macro you also need to start with the back quote. So you need `` u.IntUft=`I'"' ``.

See full example here:

```
obdc load, exec(`"select * from table_name as u, l2010 as lv where u.IntUft=`I'"') dsn("some_db") clear
```

Not sure if you need to compound the string, so it might be enough to fix the local reference.

How your second example works, despite technically also having a syntax bug, must be due to how the command `obdc` handles/cleans the string input.